# Android. Русскоязычная литература по дизайну

Tags: android, material-design, android-material

Суть проблемы в том, что, довольно тяжело освоить Material Desing для Android. Т.е. даже, в том, что, этой литературы огромное количество. Пытаюсь освоить TabLayout, NavigationDrawer. Нахожу уроки, делаю все точь в точь, но постоянно вылетает:

> Rendering Problems... и прочие ошибки.

Много времени уходит заставить заработать программу. Но понимания как все это устроено - смутное.

Я хочу получить совет от более менее продвинутого разработчика, т.к. очень не хочу потратить кучу времени на некачественную литературу. Английский у меня не важный. Подскажите литературу, в которой описывается принцип создания дизайна для android API 4-5+ (на русском, книги, ресурсы и т.д.).

UPD: Забыл уточнить! Такой момент: наверное стоит почитать и книги по дизайну до Material Desing. Особенно интересно понять, зачем в android studio такое больше количество тем Material/Holo(Ligth/Dark) внутри которых еще куча тем на выбор (ActionBar/NoActionBar/Dialog/Panel/Fullscreen и т.д.) я думаю что, это темы для конкретных активити во весь экран, или с/без ActionBar. Но "я думаю" и "я знаю что это и как использовать" разные вещи, я стремлюсь ко второму.

UPD 2: Действительно, моя ошибка - я имел ввиду версии android начиная с 4.0. Спрашиваю на счет Holo и т.д. т.к. интересно понять, как развивался android. Пусть я и не буду использовать устаревшие темы, но это не гарантирует что мне придется с ними работать. Ну а вопрос, да, общий. Но не настолько, я ограничил рамки как мог. В любом случае ответ хороший, но общий (Знаю, какой вопрос, такой ответ).

Answer (score 12):

Начнем с того, что ваш вопрос слишком общий для данного ресурса и здесь он "не формат"- здесь принято задавать вопросы с **одной** конкретной проблемой, которую можно однозначно решить, не прибегая к пространственным рассуждениям, учтите это в будущем.

Далее, по вашему вопросу видно, что у вас полная каша в голове, в частности API 4, тема Holo и Material Design находятся в диаметрально противоположных концах, если подходить к этому формально, так же , к примеру, `TabLayout` имеет такое же отношение к Material Design, как отрез китайского шелка к последней коллекции В. Зайцева (то есть то, что Зайцев использует его в моделях своей коллекции, не значит, что по наличию шелка можно говорить о руке Зайцева)
Из контекста можно понять, что на самом деле вас "мучают" не принципы Material Design, а недостаток общих знаний по верстке макетов экранов в приложении Android - по этой теме написано в **каждом** учебнике по Android и принципы эти в основном не изменились за много лет, от себя могу порекомендовать замечательную книгу от BigNerdRanch: Б.Харди - "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" - 2015 г. , найти ее можно и бесплатно без особого труда.

Теперь API4 - данное API безнадежно устарело и поддержкой таких реликтов не занимается сейчас **никто**. На самом деле многие разработчики сейчас ставят MinAPI = 16, так как процент актуальных устройств **всех** низших API составляет менее 5%, в то время, как поддержка устаревших API требует либо нетривиальных усилий от разработчика (потраченных практически в пустую), либо и вовсе разработки только с возможностями этих старых API, что в наше время ассоциируется с пользованием старым черно-белым телевизором на 12 каналов без пульта ДУ - конечно можно, но не очень то и удобно. Ознакомиться с актуальной картиной используемых в настоящее время устройств вы всегда можете по этой ссылке: [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)
Добавлю, что версия API не равна версии Android, посмотреть соответствие вы можете [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

Теперь по темам. Большое количество тем присутствует потому, что с API 11 до API 19 (Android 4) использовалась тема Holo, с API21 и до нашего времени (Android 5, 6) - Material, до API 11 (Android 2.3 и ниже) вообще тема без собственного имени - все они присутствуют в SDK и сейчас для обратной совместимости, чтобы пользователь на устройстве с Android 6 мог запустить приложение, использующее тему Holo, ну или вы, как закоренелый ретроград, могли оформить свое приложение в теме, используемой в Gingerbread, если такая прихоть придет вдруг вам в голову :)
То, какую из тем (Holo, Material или версий до android 3) использовать в своем приложении - выбирать, как разработчику, вам, исходя из собственного вкуса и иных соображений, хотя рекомендуются, конечно, быть в тренде и использовать последнюю из предложенных Google - Material.
На устройствах с API < 21 (до Android 5.0) эта тема доступна в виде официальной библиотеки поддержки Google - *AppCompat*. Соответственно и сама тема называется *AppCompat*, она в меру сил (работа по совместимости продолжается) дублирует оригинальную тему Material из API>=21. Если вы планируете использовать *Material Design* на устройствах с API ниже 21 (раньше Android 5.0), вам необходимо подключить эту библиотеку в свой проект и использовать тему *AppCompat* для своего приложения.
Тема *Holo* на устройствах с API < 11 (Gingerbread и ниже) не доступна, но и поддерживать такие устройства в настоящее время не целесообразно).

Разделение на темы Dark/Light  - это общий "окрас" темы - светлая, темная.

Подтемы ActionBar/NoActionBar/Dialog/Panel/Fullscreen задают внешний вид экрана, как нетрудно понять из их названий - с экшенбаром, без него, в виде диалога, полноэкранного приложения и тд. - так их и использовать.

конкретно по верстке есть такие книги (на русском с этим туго, но они и так понятны):

*Jason Ostrander - Android UI Fundamentals. Develop and Design*

*Luhani Lehtimaki - Smashing Android UI - 2013* - очень подробно о верстке

книги на примере Holo, поэтому проясним еще один вопрос. Material Design - это **очередная** тема для приложений Android, такая же как была до этого Holo, до нее еще. Она определяет, в основном, внешний вид, при этом принципы верстки остаются,как правило, прежними (за редкими исключениями в гайдлайнах), поэтому не стоит заострять внимание на каких то конкретных темах в пользу общих принципов - они не меняются сильно.

О основных принципах концепции Material Design вы можете ознакомиться в [здесь](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html). Полные гайдлайны, со всеми нюансами верстки, взаиморасположения всех основных элементов и правилами их размещения [доступны здесь](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). (вообще рекомендую полностью изучить официальный ресурс [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/index.html))

PS: большинство проблем связанных с Rendering Problems решается предварительной сборкой приложения, о чем и написано в сообщении, если читать его полностью. Так же это может быть вызвано тем, что некоторые стили более новых тем не поддерживаются в более старых. В частности, при желании использовать тему Holo, необходимо отказаться от библиотеки AppCompat (исключить из проекта ее и все отсылки в разметке на ее стили или ресурсы).

Вы должны знать, что визуальный редактор IDE не самое надежное место для оценки верстки приложения и использовать его рекомендуется только для предварительных "набросков" - он допускает достаточно ошибок. Реальное положение вы можете увидеть только на эмуляторе и\или реальном устройстве

Comment: я даже зачитался))

Comment: тс написал "api 4 - 5+", имея в виду "android 4 - 5+", а вы его сразу на десять лет назад отправили.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Видимо вы правы, меня тоже немного удивило такое API, но на фоне остального оно не слишком выделялось :)

Comment: @YuraIvanov в любом случае, надо было поправить ТС-а, указав, что API 4-5 очень-очень старый. И надо было рассказать о различии в API и версии андрюши,что, в принципе, и сделал **pavlofff**, сказав *"Добавлю, что версия API не равна версии Android"*. :)

Comment: @intro94 Я это добавил после комментария *Yura Ivanov*, мне как то не пришло в голову, что указав API кто то думает о мажорной версии платформы на самом деле :)

Comment: @pavlofff хитёр-бобёр, однако. XD Но ваш ответ действительно очень полезен. Добавил себе в закладки, ибо возможно когда-нибудь и мне пригодится. :)

Answer (score 3):

На русском литературы и видео по Material Design очень мало, но для начала могу посоветовать книгу

[Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 2-е издание](http://www.piter.com/collection/all/product/android-programmirovanie-dlya-professionalov-2-e-izdanie-2)

При желании и упорстве ее уже можно найти в свободном доступе.
Глава 33 книги посвящена Material Design (Глава 33. Материальное оформление).