# Как наилучшим образом обеспечить совместимость при использовании Material Design?

Tags: android

1. Я прочитал что существуют вспомогательные библиотеки v7 которые обеспечивают обратную совместимость в плоть до 7й версии API. Т.е. я могу создавать приложения 27 версии, использовать библиотеку v7 и все мои приложения будут работать до 7й версии API?
2. Так же например в документации android в разделе про Material Design -> Обеспечение совместимости, для обеспечения совместимости предлагается использовать альтернативные стили:

   > В файле res/values/styles.xml определите тему, наследующую более старую тему (например, Holo).
   >   В файле res/values-v21/styles.xml определите тему с таким же именем, наследующую тему Material Design.

   Т.е. я могу использовать api21 и выше, а для старых версий создавать альтернативные лэйауты? и тогда не надо использовать библиотеку v7?
3. Да и как вообще поступают на практике?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527223/177345

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, прочитал и понял принципиальную разницу между библиотекой совместимости AppCompat и использованием альтернативных стилей values-v*. Но я хотел уточнить ведь библиотека AppCompat предоставляет еще и дополнительные возможности из этого следует что на практике лучше отдавать предпочтение AppCompat?

Comment: в целом [мое мнение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554449/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2#comment715362_554455) по библиотекам поддержки, то есть да, их использовать предпочтительней, если они перекрывают все ваши потребности (не все входит в библиотеку поддержки из новых API, в частности, например ripple-эффект)